# Make a symmetric matrix a diagonal matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal, symmetric

I a have symmetric matrix (e.g. `M <- matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)`) and I want to set the off diagonal elements to `0`. Is there a smarter way than `diag(diag(M), ncol = ncol(M))`?

Note: `diag` does not support the usssage of `diag(M, ncol = ncol(M))` and doesn't have an option like `diag(M, as.matrix = TRUE)` etc.

Comment: `upper.tri(M) <- 0;
lower.tri(M) <- 0` Is the first thing I could think of.

Comment: Your title is a little bit misleading. I would suggest put zeros off the diagonal of a matrix.

Comment: I don't think it's misleading. Diagonal matrix is a matrix where off-diagonal elements are zero.

Comment: What do you mean by smarter? The approach you have in your post seems efficient in time, and @RonakShah's comment would be efficient in space if `M` is large.